# How to make hovered gradient button slightly darker?

Tags: html, css, hover, gradient

I have a problem with button made in css.
I want to make it slightly darker when it's hovered, but it's gradient. I don't know how to do it, and I can't find how to do it.

```css
.button {
  padding: 2%;
  width: 14%;
  height: 23%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(221, 221, 221));
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: /* problem */
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonsmenu">
  <div class="button">(...)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to change the rgb values to darker, I am sure there are online colourizer things to get you those values

Answer (score 0):

simply use a lower RGB value. The lower the value the darker the color. In this example I lowered every RGB value by 20 points:

```css
.button {
  padding: 2%;
  width: 14%;
  height: 23%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(221, 221, 221));
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(235, 235, 235), rgb(201, 201, 201));
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonsmenu">
  <div class="button">(...)</div>
</div>
```